# How to access functions in Detail.controller.js in Master.controller.js?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I changed name of detail controller to DetailController.js

I tried

```
jQuery.sap.require("cts.alert.controller.DetailController");
```

And

```
sap.ui.define([
        "cts/alert/controller/DetailController",
], function () {
})
```

in MasterController.js,

when I use `this.detailfunction()`, it returned `undefined`(But it works in BaseController? )

Then I tried `sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview3--detailpage").getController().detailfunction()`:

`sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview3--detailpage")` returned the view , but getController is undefined. What should I do ?

Comment: is your DetailController really named DetailController.controller.js?

Comment: DetailController.js won't work?  I think BaseController.js works OK. @Marc

Comment: Controllers that are directly used by views have to be named Bla *.controller*.js (thats one of the main features the custom SAP module loader implements ;). A baseclass of a controller is a regular class that should not have the *.controller*.js extension. It is not recommended to use the base controller directly in a view. Inherit from it in a otherwise empty *.controller*.js and use that in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an utility method it might make sense to move the code up, to the Base, assuming both controllers extend it. If not, create a third utility module and inject it in both master and detail.

Comment: I understand. I used setInterval in Detail, and I want to clear it after click nav button in Master. So should I save the interval id to the third module? I don't wan't to make interval id global. Thanks~

Comment: In that case, you could have a global jsonmodel used to store the application state. Without knowing more details of your app structure I'd say that ID would belong in there. With that in place, you read/write to that model from both views. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much , I understand, just like the `busy` state. That helps.